# Yii2 installation using composer giving error

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am trying to install Yii2 alpha. When I run the following command after downloading composer and adding

```
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

to composer.json.

```
$ php composer.phar require yiisoft/yii2-framework "*"
```

I get the following error.

**Problem 1**
    - The requested package minimum-stability could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

**Problem 2**
    - The requested package yiisoft/yii2-composer could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

**Problem 3**
    - The requested package yiisoft/yii2-framework could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

**Potential causes**:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.

Read http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

start with

```
php composer.phar init
```

and set Minimum Stability[] to dev

then

```
php composer.phar require yiisoft/yii2 "*"
```

Comment: I had issue with webvimark module installation, above solution by @user1852788 worked :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is working composer.json code

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    ...
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
            "php": ">=5.4.0",
            "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
    },
    "require-dev": {
            "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
            "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*"
    },
    ...
}
```

Use yii2 against yii2-framework, may be you typed "minimum-stability" in the wrong place. And you don't need type yii2-composer there, it will be installed automatically

Comment: I used the template above with the typo (an extra comma) "yiisoft/yii2": "*", removed. But still the same result. Problem 1
    - The requested package yiisoft/yii2-framework could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.